# AJAX call not working for sending tokens to API in Django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have a token and need to pass it to an API (created in views.py) in order to get back a time that's generated. I have used ***Simple-JWT*** for token generation but I am not able to send it to the URL specified. See my code below:

**models.py:**

```
class My_time(models.Model):
    id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

**views.py:**

```
#API to get back time (if existing) or create a new time and send it back to the HTML page via AJAX.

class TimeAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] 
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        current_time = timezone.now()
        if (My_time.objects.filter(time=current_time) in (None, '')): 
            time = My_time.objects.create(time=current_time) #saves it to my database
        else:
            pass
        data = My_time.objects.values_list('time', flat=True)
        return data #should return the data to the HTML page
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = My_time
        fields = ('time')
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
     # ...,
     path('time_api/',TimeAPI.as_view(), name = 'time_api'),
]
```

**interface.html:**

```
{% block content %}
        <form method="POST">           
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" id ='get_time'> Punch In </button> 
            <h4 id='display_time'></h4>
        </form>

{% endblock content%}
```

**JS code (within the HTML page):**

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#get_time').click(function () {
            var access_token = localStorage.getItem('access');  #stored the token before in localStorage
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,  
                url: {% url 'time_api' %},
                method: 'GET', 
                // datatype: 'json',
                headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token }
                success: function(data) {  
                    console.log(headers);
                    document.getElementById("display_time").innerHTML(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log("No data");
                }
                });
        });

    </script>

{% endblock javascript %}
```

After clicking the button within my HTML page, I am not getting back the time generated. In fact, nothing happens.

**This is the error within JS console:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

**and it points to the success function in AJAX:**

```
headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token }
success: function(data) {  
    console.log(headers);
..... //remaining code
```

Can someone please explain what's wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try using the browser developer tools and check the js console output and include that here  and also try to override the get method of your CBV  and check for `if self.request.is_ajax`  and return the data you need.  that could be the issue

Comment: I have added the error message. Please take a look.

Comment: and perhaps  modify your js error handler to take the data argument only like  `error:function(data){console.log('No data');         console.log(data);}`  then check what the js console prints out.

Comment: The `get` method is the one responsible for returning data to templates, the `get_queryset` method controls what data is included in the response  and can be used to filter the objects to be returned

Answer (score 0):

modify your error handler to only accept the `data` argument and log it to the console.

the error is in the js function

Comment: I removed the error handler. But it still does the same thing. It doesnt access the API

Comment: Should I change to get method instead of get_queryset?

Answer (score 0):

define a new method  `def get(self,request):  queryset=self.get_queryset()#  construct your html response  and construct a json response   and returñ that`  then in js  access the data value with `data.value`

Comment: if you return a json  set the html content with `document.getElementById('your_id').text(data.value)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but is it possible to format your answer? I am not able to understand it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

define a new method  `def get(self,request):  queryset=self.get_queryset()#  construct your html response  and construct a json response   and returñ that`  then in js  access the data value with `data.value

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

def get(self, response):
    data = self.get_queryset()
    # assuming data is a dict object
    return Response(data)
```